# (OnsenUi) Problems when using Animate.css and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animate.css, onsen-ui

I am using [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in my OnsenUI project.

#### Here is my Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/b1qHW7?p=preview

**The actual drill:**
- When I click the `Present Page 2` button, the `page2.html` should appear.
- When I click the `X` button, `page2.html` should pop.
- The `heart` is a toggle button which works as a like button. (I have used Animate.css for this only)

**The problem:**
After the `heart` button is clicked, the `X` button doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bug! It will be tracked in OnsenUI github issues.

https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/117